# Sql where problems when a +-mark is in the search string

Tags: mysql, sql

I am searching for products in the termek table.

Product name:

```
Leier Leiertherm 30 N+F tégla
```

or

```
Leier Plan 10/50 N+F tégla, LeierFix univerzális ragasztóhabbal - 10 x 50 x 24,9 cm
```

I type in these words into the search field, and when searching, I didn't get any result. I think, there are problems with the + or - marks. I can't rename the products to an other name.

Can someone help me?

```
$keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($kapcs, $_GET['k']);
$get_hirek_2 = mysqli_query($kapcs, "SELECT termek_id, termek_nev, termek_seo, termek_brutto, termek_akcios, termek_egyseg, termek_desc, termek_thumb FROM termek WHERE termek_nev LIKE '%$keyword%' OR termek_desc LIKE '%$keyword%' ORDER BY termek_nev ASC LIMIT 50");
```

Comment: There's nothing special about `+` in SQL.

Comment: So, whats the problem? I can found any products, execpt these.

Comment: Try using a prepared statement instead of substituting variables.

Comment: I dont understand. Can you show me some code?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem long time ago ,
the following solved it , I dont know if it will be good solution for you

```
$temp_findkeyword = "%".$_POST['findkeyword']."%"; 
$search = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 like '$temp_findkeyword');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a prepared statement instead of variable substitution, it's also better protection from SQL injection than using `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($kapcs, "SELECT termek_id, termek_nev, termek_seo, termek_brutto, termek_akcios, termek_egyseg, termek_desc, termek_thumb 
        FROM termek 
        WHERE termek_nev LIKE ? OR termek_desc LIKE ? 
        ORDER BY termek_nev ASC LIMIT 50");
$pattern = "%{$_GET['k']}%';
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $pattern, $pattern);
myqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($id, $nev, $seo, $brutto, $akcios, $egyseg, $desc, $thumb);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    // Use the variables from mysqli_stmt_bind_result() here
}
```